# Set Last Six Digit Regex Patterns for HTML5 Text field

Tags: html, regex

The validation I need for regex is to check only if the input has last six digit on the input.
Sample Accepted Input name are as follows:

- Juan Dela Cruz 123456
- Juan Dela Cruz | 123456

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="employee">Employee Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="employee" name="employee" pattern="([0-9]{6})$" title="Last Six Number"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern instead:

```
.*([0-9]{6})$
```

That way, the entire value (including anything before the digits) matches.  `.*` in RegEx matches anything.

```
  <input
    type="text"
    id="employee"
    name="employee"
    pattern=".*([0-9]{6})$"
    title="Last Six Number"
  >
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ek9gmunh/

Comment: @espongha Woot, I'm glad!  You can accept this answer if you'd like by checking the checkmark next to it.